# Error connecting to a WCF Service hosted on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2008, remote-debugging

I have created a console app using VS2012 which i am using as Client to connect to WCF service which is Deployed on Dev Server(IIS 8)(Windows Server 2012)

console app

```
    WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
    EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://...");
    CVT_ServiceClient Client = new CVT_ServiceClient(binding, epa);
```

I have enabled debugging in my web.config file of WCF Service

I am getting this error while connecting
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error *connecting* to the server, this appears to be an error *debugging the server remotely*. If you intend to debug remotely, install the remote debugger at the server. If not, debug "just my code".